# How to parse an OpenAPI schema and convert a component, including all references, to JSON Schema?

Tags: python, openapi, jsonschema

> How to parse an OpenAPI schema and convert a component, including all references, to JSON Schema?

I have output that I need to validate against specific component(s) of an OpenAPI spec. I have already looked at `schemathesis`, but it doesn't seem to support my use case:

https://schemathesis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#schemathesis.models.APIOperation

Is there anyway to take an OpenAPI spec, reference a component, and generate the equivalent JSON Schema, with all references included?